# Decrease DC voltage using resistors without decreasing current

Tags: power-supply, voltage, resistors

How would one go about using a 12 V DC, 1 A power source to power something which needs 9.5 V DC, 1 A using resistors?

Comment: Unless whatever it is always draws the same amount of current, the voltage drop across the resistor is going to vary and the voltage supplied will vary. That may or may not be acceptable for your needs, but this is why that approach isn't often used.

Comment: Exactly what is this thing that needs 9.5VDC and 1A?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. People can help you take the next step but your question should show as much as possible, which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Describe the problem you are trying to solve, with all your own work and own findings so far in detail. Add a schematic, the schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> How would one go about using a 12 V DC, 1 A power source to power something which needs 9.5 V DC, 1 A using resistors?

You wouldn't. Not with resistors. Not to a 'something'.

If the something was a pure resistor, then you could calculate a suitable dropping resistor to provide the voltage drop.

However if the 'something' consumes a variable current, then the voltage drop across a dropping resistor would vary with the current consumption, and potentially take the input voltage up to damage levels or down to non-working levels.

The ideal would be use use a regulator, which would provide the exact voltage required at all current levels.

For a crude dropper, you could use a few diodes in series, that would have a relatively constant voltage drop over a wide range of current.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help